# MSSQL Transaction - INSERT only IF SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I am looking for the best transaction/locking solution to this problem for MSSQL.

I have the following table - call it 'payments'

```
paymentId    accountId    amount
--------------------------------
1            1            100
2            1            -50
3            1            100
4            2            200 
5            2            -60
```

So we have our account balances:

```sql
select [accountId], sum([amount]) as balance 
from [payments] 
group by [accountId]
```

```
accountId     balance
---------------------
1             150
2             140
```

---

I want to insert a new payment but first check in an atomic manner if the balance of the account will go into the negative.

Whats is the best way I can do this while keeping locks low?

Here is an unsafe version for starters:

```sql
declare @accountId as int
declare @newPaymentAmount as int

declare @balance as int
set @balance = select sum([balance]) from [payments] where [accountId] = @accountId

if @balance + @newPaymentAmount > 0
  insert into [payments] ([accountId], [amount]) values (@accountId, @newPaymentAmount)
else
  throw
```

Comment: You probably need a trigger for this.

Comment: Or, alternatively, you could handle the `INSERT` statements via an SP; which would allow you to check the aggregate value(s) first.

Comment: You can't really keep locks "low" in the sense that doing this atomically inevitably requires taking range locks for at least all the rows of that account -- anything less allows the result to be invalidated. This is a typical scenario for `SERIALIZABLE`. To actually reduce locks you'd need to start storing data redundantly, i.e. calculate and keep the balance up to date with every transaction so you can read it off by locking just one row. Of course, keeping redundant data has its own problems.

Comment: @Larnu yes a SP will be how we execute the block of code.

Comment: @JeroenMostert what will the `SERIALIZABLE` look like?

Comment: Easy enough -- `SET XACT_ABORT ON`; `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE`; `BEGIN TRANSACTION`; do it all; `COMMIT`. The nice thing about atomic transactions is that the database makes it easy to use them. The not so nice thing is that it might lock more than you bargained for, of course. Then again, something about premature optimization and the root of all evil...

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
begin transaction 
declare @accountId as int
declare @newPaymentAmount as int

declare @balance as int
set @balance = select sum([balance]) 
               from [payments] with (updlock, serializable) 
               where [accountId] = @accountId

if @balance + @newPaymentAmount > 0
  insert into [payments] ([accountId], [amount]) values (@accountId, @newPaymentAmount)
else
  throw . . .
commit transaction
```

Making the transaction SERIALIZABLE will techncially also work here, but it will allow multiple sessions to run the first query, then cause a deadlock on the INSERT.  So it's better to just block the second session before it reads the data, so it can proceed after the first one is finished.

Comment: Will not this lock the entire table due to aggregation?

Comment: `accountId` should be the leading column in the clustered index, and and only the rows with that `accountId` will be locked.

Comment: Tried to run it in 2 different sessions with different `accountId`. The second aggregation apparently is waiting for the first transaction to commit.

Comment: Were the `accountId`s sequential?  The range lock will lock the "next" value too. See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2006/05/26/range-locks/

Comment: Yes, they were sequential.

Answer (score 0):

use merge statement

```
MERGE INTO payments AS TARGET 
USING (select sum([balance]) as amount, accountId from [payments] where [accountId] = @accountId group by accountId) AS SOURCE 
on(Source.accountId = Target.accountId and amount + newPaymentAmount > 0) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
insert into [payments] ([accountId], [amount]) values (@accountId, @newPaymentAmount);
```

Comment: Using MERGE instead of two seperate queries doesn't help.  The "match" phase of the MERGE isn't run with any exclusive locking by default, and so two concurrent sessions can run the "match" and then both run the insert.  See eg https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2013/02/25/why-is-tsql-merge-failing-with-a-primary-key-violation-isnt-it-atomic/

Comment: Plus, all the potential issues if one fails to [Use Caution With SQL Server's Merge Statement](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM dbo.payments

declare @accountId as INT=1
declare @newPaymentAmount as INT=-800

declare @balance as int
set @balance = (SELECT sum(ISNULL([amount],0)) from [payments] where [accountId] = @accountId)

SELECT @balance
if @balance + @newPaymentAmount > 0
  insert into [payments] ([accountId], [amount]) values (@accountId, @newPaymentAmount)
else
  RAISERROR('Insufficeint Balance',16,1)

Comment: The code you posted isn't functionally any different than the code the OP included in the question. It doesn't address atomicity, race conditions, or locking, which are at the heart of the question.